# using color ink when printing only black documents

Tags: printing, printer

I have an hp photosmart 5514...I print 100% black.........I recently changed all color and black cartridges..........I made ONE copy of a printed letter (black) using the gray scale setting.........I checked the ink level with the new cartridges and the magenta cartridge shows a gap at the top as if I made several color copies...............why am I using so much color ink even using the gray scale setting? Thank you , Frank

Comment: thanks kevinrob............although there are a lot of answers that make sense , I still think the real answer lies in the fact that whomever makes the printers , "THEY" want to keep us connected so we HAVE TO KEEP BUYING INK from the gougers...........

Answer (score 0):

Some printers are preparing all cartridges for printing. If the printer don't print, a little quantity of ink is wasted in a recuperator.

- http://www.atomicshrimp.com/st/content/inkjet_printer
- http://www.nifty-stuff.com/canon-waste-ink-tank-waste-ink-pads.php
- https://www.google.ch/search?q=printer+waste+ink